# openssl_encrypt and Crypto JS

Tags: javascript, php, pdf, encryption

I'm trying to encrypt a file in PHP and decrypt in JS, using CryptoJS as a library to decrypt.

Code to encrypt:

```
$e = openssl_encrypt(mb_convert_encoding($data, "UTF-8"), $method, hex2bin($key), 0, hex2bin($iv));
$fp = fopen($destination, 'w')
$write = fwrite($fp, bin2hex( base64_decode( $e )))
```

And in the client side i'm using the following code to generate the pdf

```
window.open("data:application/pdf;base64," + btoa(decrypted.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8)),"Testing");
```

When it tries to generate the pdf, returns the error below:

```
InvalidCharacterError: String contains an invalid character
...n("data:application/pdf;base64," + btoa(decrypted.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8)),"...
```

The initial PDF document was generated using MPDF library, however if i upload this pdf using a form, works well, if i generate the pdf, store in a folder and try to encrypt, returns the error above.

Thanks

**EDITED**

After running a couple of more tests, i've realized the problem is between the $mpdf->output("..",F); and opening the file to encrypt.

If i comment the line where i create the pdf, the encrypt function works well, if i do one after other, the encrypted file doesn't work.

Seems to have a conflict between the output buffers or something similar.

Any idea how to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: Why are you trying to use `btoa` when CryptoJS is perfectly capable of producing Base64-encoded strings: `decrypted.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64)`

Comment: Avoid the UTF-8 things, too! A PDF is a binary file!